# Open with selection starts wrong program

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 - File Explorer - I right-click a .jpg filename.  When I use Open With in the pop-up and select a program to use (in this case, ViewNX2), it starts Share instead. If I select Choose Another App and select ViewNX2, it works fine.  Default association for .jpg files is Windows Photo Viewer.  Have not seen this problem with any other programs in Open_With.

Comment: ViewNX2 doesn't use a 'file open' strategy at all [unless it is massively different from the much newer ViewNX-i, which I'd highly recommend.. though why you'd use it for jpgs I'm not sure, it's a RAW editor] it uses a 'library hierarchy' type structure - so you launch the app, then navigate to your photos folder. It stores edit data in that folder, as NKSC sidecar files, which isn't good on a loose file structure.

Comment: ViewNX2 works as 'file open' for me. But not in the scenario I detailed.  Also does as great job editing .jpg's.

Comment: Then I've no idea. I've never used NX2, it hasn't been supported in 5 years or more. It doesn't support Windows 10 or macOS newer than 10.10 - https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/download/sw/20.html It was discontinued & replaced by NX-i in 2015. [It's still freeware]